# Python newline display in console

Tags: python

So, when I try to print help/info of Python functions `function.__doc__`, the console output instead of printing a newline when `\n` occurs in the doc string, prints `\n`. Can anyone help me with disabling/helping out with this?

This is my output:

```
'divmod(x, y) -> (div, mod)\n\nReturn the tuple ((x-x%y)/y, x%y).  Invariant: div*y + mod == x.'
```

What I would like the output to be:

```
   'divmod(x, y) -> (div, mod)

    Return the tuple ((x-x%y)/y, x%y).  Invariant: div*y + mod == x.'
```

P.S: I have tried this on OS X, Ubuntu with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like you inspected the object in the interactive shell, not printed it. If you mean print, write it.

```
>>> "abc\n123"
"abc\n123"
>>> print "abc\n123"
abc
123
```

In python 3.x print is an ordinary function, so you have to use (). The following (recommended) will work in both 2.x and 3.x:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print("abc\n123")
abc
123
```

Comment: Yes. So from what I understand, to 'unsee' the '\n', I should use the print instead of just typing [function].__doc__ ?

Comment: Yes. It will also leave off the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You might find it more helpful to use (for example) `help(divmod)` instead of `divmod.__doc__`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [6]: print divmod.__doc__
divmod(x, y) -> (div, mod)

Return the tuple ((x-x%y)/y, x%y).  Invariant: div*y + mod == x.
```

but i suggest you use

```
In [8]: help(divmod)
```

or in IPYTHON

```
In [9]: divmod?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
Base Class: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
String Form:<built-in function divmod>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
divmod(x, y) -> (div, mod)

Return the tuple ((x-x%y)/y, x%y).  Invariant: div*y + mod == x.
```